# Windows API or codebase for fast audio input using QT 4?

Tags: windows, qt, audio

I write a free software defined radio application, SdrDx. Qt 4, under Windows, limits audio sample rates to 48 kHz(!); I need a minimum of 192 kHz. After trying for over a year to get the QT people to move on this -- to the point of finding the offending hard limit in their source code and pointing it out to them -- I've given up trying to get them to fix this. So, unless I can find something that will work, I am about to close my windows branch. The Mac branch samples just fine up to 192 khz, so that's ok... sadly, it'll be something that I will conditionally compile in for Windows branch only. Anyone have any pointers as to anything that will work for XP and up, within the Qt environment?

At this point, even a pointer to a raw Microsoft sound card API known to be fast might be helpful. Maybe I could build an external program that grabs sound and messages it over TCP to me. Something. Anything. I'm ready to pull my hair out.

Comment: Errrm...is your radio application for dog whistles, or aliens?  Ever heard of the  [Nyquist Sampling Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)?  48kHz is already over the top for the general human ear: CD sound is perfectly fine and manages at 44kHz.  What-the-heck-are-you-doing?

Comment: The sample rate is baseband radio up to (in this case) 192 khz, within which are *Radio* stations (not audio), which my application demodulates and turns *into* audio. The concept is that there is hardware that can, for instance, hand me 192 khz translated from 1 mhz, and then what the app sees is 0...192 khz, which is actually 1.000 mhz to 1.192 mhz, or about 19 AM channels. SDR stands for software defined radio; look it up, it's pretty easy to understand and you might find it interesting.

Comment: @fyngrz I see.  Well, that sort of application is pretty far outside of Qt's priorities in terms of platform abstraction.  If there's a hard limit it may be in there for a good reason (or a bad one), or it might not be there for any reason at all.  If your question linked to the line and your report, it might make it more actionable for any Qt'ers in the know...