# Sample rate 192 kHz using Qt 5.3

Tags: c++, qt

I need to capture and play audio in high samle rate=192 kHz.

I have the corresponding hardware (external sound card).

The function supportedSampleRates() returns me constantly QList which consisted of [8000,11025,22050,44100,48000, 96000], even if I chouse different availableDevices

```
QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> devicesOutput = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput);
QAudioDeviceInfo infoOutExt(devicesOutput.at(1));
QList<int> rateOutExt=infoOutExt.supportedSampleRates();
```

Can I get 192 kHz in Qt 5.3?

Comment: Is the hardware actually capable of doing 192 kHz? search how to find audio device property for your operating system.

Comment: It seems that there are limitations for audio sample rate in implementations of Qt for different operating systems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257082/windows-api-or-codebase-for-fast-audio-input-using-qt-4